# how to get correct user id on page

Tags: 7, users, theming

I've added two custom fields to my user form - `field_license` and `field_download_date`. In my `preprocess_page` function, I'm doing this:

```
if(isset($vars['user'])) {
   $user_data = user_load($vars['user']->uid);
   error_log("userdata");
   error_log(print_r($user_data, 1));
}
```

I'm not trying to get the current user info, but a specific user. When I look at the error log, though, `$user_data` is printing out the info of the user I'm logged in as, not the user that's displaying on the page based on the URL (mysite.com/user/2). How do I get the data for the user based on the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
user_load(arg(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

For getting user based on current page, you can try to use `$account = menu_get_object('user')` code.
Var $account will contain user object.
Read more about this function here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7

Comment: @EmmyS this is a better long term option - even the description of arg() says not to use it unless absolutely necessary - this option allows you to customise urls so they don't need to include the id (user/fred) instead of (user/2)

Comment: Thanks, @Geoff. I'm not actually using this code as-is; I just needed to be able to print out the values temporarily. For that, `user_load(arg(1))` works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

you can use 
global $user;
$user_id = $ser->uid;

Comment: That gets the current logged-in user, not the user being viewed.